# Why does ObjectOutputStream.readObject() return object of type Object and not object of type I wrote it in?

Tags: java, object, casting, stream

Say I have class `Car`:

```
class Car implements Serializable{
    String color;
    
    public Car(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Now I want to write **object** of class `Car` into `ObjectStream`. So it looks like this:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("obj.dat"));
oos.writeObject(new Car("yellow"));
```

And then of course I would like to read **object**! So I would need to do this:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("obj.dat"));
Car car = (Car)ois.readObject();
```

My question is following: Why does method `readObject()` return `Object` and not `Car`? Doesn't my file `obj.dat` store all information about **objects** it holds? So no doubt it knows **object** I want to **read** is of type `Car`. So why it doesn't simply return `Car`, so that I don't have to do any **casting**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* return a `Car` in this case.

But the compiler can't know that at compile time, because it depends on the data in `obj.dat`.

So the compiler has to assume the general case. The only thing it knows for sure is that `readObject()` will return some `Object`.

You can cast it to a more specific type if you know it will always be that, just as you did.

Or think about it the other way around: if you serialized a `Car` object and a `Bike` object after each other in the same file, then calling `readObject()` twice should return those two types.

Now the return type of that method is defined statically, so there's no way in the Java type system for the first call to indicate a different return type than the second call.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has no way of knowing what type of object is in the file/serialized data.